# How to license a book as open-source

Tags: licensing

I'm writing a small book in software development practices and I want to licensed it as open-source, but I don't how these license thing works. Thanks

Comment: This question shouldn't really be on stackoverflow.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing/legal advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to be really clear about what you want to achieve. Do you want to earn money on it in any way or from things like corporate customers? Or maybe you just want to let it out for free for anyone to use as they please. In the latter case, you don't really need any licensing at all.

After you have figured out what you want to achieve, we can help you further.

Comment: Hi David, I want to give away the book for free but to be recognized as the author.

Comment: If you do not add a license, it's not free by default; see here: http://choosealicense.com/no-license/

Answer (score 3):

You may wish to start your search at the [creative commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/) family of licenses, which provide pre-written licenses with a variety of features (non-commercial use only vs commercial use allowed, etc).

Using pre-written software licenses is probably not the best starting point for anything but software.